# Cannot change the Builder settings in Eclipse for TexLipse

Tags: texlipse, eclipse

I moved recently to Eclipse Photon and strangely I can no longer change the Builder properties to select the MikTex bin path. Here is the pop-up that I get:

[image]

Any tips are welcome. 
Regards

Comment: This may be a bug/change in Eclipse and/or TexLipse, so you could try reporting an issue to them instead of here to increase your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there was a compatibility issue between Eclipse Photon and the installation image from sourceforge.net . Installing Texlipse plugging from the Marketplace worked like a charm.